# near-bindgen macro: unsupported argument type

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am writing a smart contract promise interface for NEAR blockchain.

I have the following interface:

```rust
#[ext_contract(token_receiver)]
pub trait ExtTokenReceiver {

    fn process_token_received(&self, sender_id: AccountId, amount: Balance, message: [u8]) -> Option<String>;
}
```

However this fails with the following error:

```
error: Unsupported argument type.
  --> src/token.rs:32:1
   |
32 | #[ext_contract(token_receiver)]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

- How can I debug near-bindgen macro
- What is the `Unsupported argument type` in this case
- How to fix my interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the unsupported arguments is [u8]. I have changed the code to use Vec and it works:

```
use near_sdk::ext_contract;

#[ext_contract(token_receiver)]
pub trait ExtTokenReceiver {
    fn process_token_received(
        &self,
        sender_id: AccountId,
        amount: Balance,
        message: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> Option<String>;
}
```

```
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.05s
```

What I believe is the issue that the compiler doesn't know the size of the static array at compile time and complains, and Vec as it is a dynamic container that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question it says: run nightly with `-Z macro-backtrace`, which you can do by editing the project's `build.sh`.  Another tool to debug macros in rust is to use [cargo-expand](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-expand), which will decompile from the altered AST.

For the second and third questions: my guess is that it is the `[u8]`, which is an array that must be known at compile time.  You should use `Vec<u8>`, which can be coerced into a `&[u8]` where needed.